# User processed link references in Markdig?

Tags: c#, .net, markdown, commonmark

When compiling Markdown to HTML, I need to support something like `` [`C`] `` which refers to a language's item in the scope. If a link reference doesn't exist, it should solve to an item in my language.

I gave a look at `MarkdownPipelineBuilder`, but found no way to specify a custom processor for these links. This is all `MarkdownPipeline` has of public:

```
BlockParsers
InlineParsers
Extensions
PreciseSourceLocation
DebugLog
TrackTrivia
DocumentProcessed
Build
```

I think the internal [LinkInlineParser.ProcessLinkReference](https://github.com/xoofx/markdig/blob/b7cb169fd3a924e1e0d4e2e487a22c51caaedd10/src/Markdig/Parsers/Inlines/LinkInlineParser.cs#L119) is relevant for a fork. How would I change it so I can pass a callback that is executed when a link is not found?